# How can i use OpenCv/Machine learning concepts in android development, i want to use few machine learning based ideas in an android app

Tags: android, opencv, machine-learning

Any recommendation on the topic is appreciated, is it even possible or not, and if it does then any links to simple projects which utilizes these concepts. The question mainly concerns with the writing the code... Is it possible to import OpenCv libraries in Android Studio, Do i need to learn (advance) python to be better at the project or java is enough? Can i copy-paste the code i wrote in VsCode (in python) in my android studio project?

An idea that i have is creating a motion detection android app, a simple 20 line python code in an android app for practice, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general suggestion is to find a simple project which has used OpenCV in Android on Github and try to replicate it from scratch. There are many great projects which also have nice documentation on how the code is built. To answer your questions:

Yes, you can import OpenCV libraries in Android Studio, but the process is more complex than Python. This [blog post](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c) nicely explains the process from the beginning.

OpenCV code can be written in Python, Java, and C++. So you don't need to learn advanced Python to begin developing projects with it.

No, although the some methods are similar, you can't copy-paste Python code in Android Studio. You need to write the code completely in Java.

If it was possible in Python, it will be possible in Android as well. Just refer to OpenCV documentation to find the Java equivalent of the functions and methods you've used in Python.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and explaining it, it seems better when somebody directs you in a direction.